# create logfile for R session that stores info, error, warnings in R

Tags: r, logging, rscript

I want to create a log file which should have info, errors, warnings, commands just like similar to RStduio console. save that in a text file.

I've tried savehistory(), sink(), Rcmd() function. but none of them are working since I'm running the R codes in non Rgui environment. is there any other possibilities to do that.

Comment: Check out `sink()`, which will reroute _everything_ to a file. Also, "does not work" tells us nothing of your actual error - what did you try, what did you expect, and what happened?

Comment: tried this,  log_file <- "path/session_log.txt"
log_connection <- file(log_file, open = "a")
sink(log_connection, type = c("output", "message", "warning", "error"))
cat("Starting the script...\n")
warning("This is a warning message.")
stop("This is an error message.")
cat("Processing data...\n")
sink()
close(log_connection)
But it doesn't capture anything in text file

Comment: @Lincy Is the logfile even being created? If its empty, delete it and re run the code.

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover yes, it creates the log file, deleted and run again, still it doesn't capture anything

Answer (score 1):

`sink()` does not take all of those arguments. I got output running this code.

```
log_file <- "c:/data/session_log.txt" 
log_connection <- file(log_file, open = "a") 
sink(log_connection, type="message") 
cat("Starting the script...\n") 
warning("This is a warning message.") 
stop("This is an error message.") 
cat("Processing data...\n") 
sink() 
close(log_connection)
```

Comment: Tried this too, but the file doesn't capture anything